# Why is $(document).ready(function() not working but jQuery(document).ready(function($) is?

Tags: jquery

I've been struggling with a script and receiving the following error:
"TypeError: $ is not a function" in the console.

This problem is happening in both Firefox and IE.

After a lot of head scratching I changed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

into...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

and the function started working.

I've been trying to find out why this should work and the differences between these two function prefixes and I've managed to glean that it is something to do with the $ not being set up correctly for jquery (or something along those lines).

I wondered if someone could, in laymans terms, explain to me why one method works and the other doesn't and also clarify the best way of prefixing a jquery function.

Many thanks.

*Edit*
To elucidate further, my project is based on Wordpress and uses several 'plugins'. It is possible that one of these has potentially caused an issue and 'redefined' $ (which, based on the answers/comments so far, I guessing has happened). I will dig deeper into this based on this new knowledge and also look into the jquery.noConflict() function to see how implementing this could help in this situation. Thank you all for your excellent help.

Comment: are you using any JS frameworks other than Jquery?

Comment: `$ === jQuery`, so the only way I can see this happening is if you've included code after jQuery that redefines `$`.

Comment: Are you using another library that could also use the "$" as a name for a function?

Comment: Is there any other javascript libraries around?  There might be conflict with `$`-wrapper.

Comment: Please provide the script included in your page

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers. I have updated my original question with a bit more information.

Comment: Several Wordpress plugins use other frameworks like MooTools (http://mootools.net/) if I recall correctly - the dollar sign is used in that framework.

Answer (score 2):

The only way for you to find out what happened to `$` is open up the Dev Console and type `$`. Then investigate what is inside the API to find out what library it is pointing to. jQuery by default uses `$` so it must getting overwritten somewhere.

Comment: To expand on this answer: many other libraries also use `$`, so it's pretty common for this to occur. In fact, jQuery even provides a method, `jQuery.noConflict()`, that intentionally resets the value of `$`. Is it possible you're calling that somewhere?

Comment: @Elliot I've just done a search and found the noConflict call in a few places within my project. It is a Wordpress project so it is being used in 3 different 'plugins'. I'll Google the noConflict call to find out more. Thank you for the information.